# Searchable and Refreshable View in SwiftUI is glitching on ObservableObject changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a SwiftUI `List` which should both have a search bar and enable pull to refresh.

In theory, this is very simple. However, there is a search bar bug whenever I update any `@Published` properties in the `.refreshable { }` code.

My view looks like this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           List {
               Text("hello")
           }
           .refreshable {
               model.prop = "world"
           }
        }
        .searchable(text: $text)
    }
}
```

And my model looks like this:

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var prop = ""
}
```

I've tried putting the update in an async block, but it did not solve the problem:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    model.prop = "world"
}
```

Any non-`ObservableObject`-mutating code inside of the `.refreshable { }` block works perfectly fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: move .searchable to be on the List instead of the NavigationView

Comment: I've tried putting .searchable both before and after .refreshable on the list, but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but with large naviation bar...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718110/swiftui-refreshable-large-navigation-titile-jumps-when-pull-to-refresh-is-eng